# List all comments in a Numbers document?

Tags: numbers

I am working on a Numbers document that has a lot of comments.  I know I can look at the individual comments, but is there any way to get a list of all the comments in the document?  I'm probably missing something simple here, but I'm absolutely terrible with Numbers.  Thanks!

Comment: You can get the list of comments if you choose to print the spreadsheet and then download it as pdf. See https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/numbers/tan9cb3153b0/mac